# "Cannot find symbol class keyboard reader" -- JCreator

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am getting the error, "Cannot find symbol class keyboard reader." What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Looping 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();
 int choice = 0;

//Menu with options
do {   
System.out.println("Looping Menu");
System.out.println("1. For Loop");
(And so on, with a menu and options that work fine)
}
}
```

Comment: PLEASE edit your question to better ask

Answer (score -1):

You need to import that class before using it.